# swift 3 perform selector with argument

Tags: ios, swift3, selector, performselector

How do you call a function based on a function name String var and pass in an argument to the function? I was trying to do this is Swift and finally got it.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 3 - inbound 'params' as [String: Any], where params["function"] == "getSomeData"

```
let funcName = String(format: "%@:", (params["function"] as? String)!)
let selector = NSSelectorFromString(funcName)
self.perform(selector, with: params)

func getSomeData(_ params: [String: Any]) {
  print(params)
}
```

Comment: Your solution works, but is not recommended. Swift is moving away from creating selectors from strings. I would not be at all surprised if Swift removes this ability completely in the near future. Rather, you should use the Swift version of the function signature, and NOT build a selector from a string at all.

Comment: what is the recommended way?

Comment: Yes Duncan C, thanks for your feedback; but sorry but it isn't very constructive? where the code behind this advice?

Comment: @VinuDavidJose having classes conform to protocols